# After clicked URL to another page and scroll

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, templates

I have one page website and couple of generic pages. I am not sure how to achieve the solution when the user click a link which redirect the user to the homepage from a generic page. After the user is on the homepage I want it to automatically scroll down to a section call id="contactForm">

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Could you please add what you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `href` of `<a>` tag, write like this `"link-to-homepage#contactForm"`

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<nav class="header-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#aboutus">Company</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#careers">Careers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contactus">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>      
<section id="aboutus">
    content here
</section>
<section id="services">
    content here
</section>
<section id="careers">
    content here
</section>
<section id="contactus">
    content here
</section>
```

JS

```
jQuery(".header-menu a").click(function(e) {
    var speed = 2000;
    var position = jQuery(jQuery(this).attr("href")).offset().top;
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: position
    }, speed, "linear");
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the link you need to place the id of the section(home page). Like

```
<a href="index.php#section-id">Click</a>
```

If you place the above code any where in your site, it will redirect you to index.php and scrolled to the section of which the id is given.

Hope it helps.